# How to hide content on a sidebar depending on the jenkins page?

Tags: javascript, css, jenkins, html

I use `simple theme plugin` and inject css to hide sidebar, but all page sidebar is hided, there is also some page I don't want hide, for example http://xxx/job/job_name, how to do that ?

Comment: Use Role Strategy plugin to Manage and Assign permissions. Based on logged in user  and according to permissions the respective content will be displayed.

Comment: I'm embeding jenkins to my website and i just wan to hide the whole sidebar on the page `http://jenkins_host/job/xxx`

Comment: If you are adding jenkins to your web, isn't there a way you could select the CSS class and just "kill it"? with a `display: none`?